# How do I access a CakePHP 1.3 view via its controller such that the URL route conforms to application/controller/view

Tags: php, windows, iis, server, cakephp-1.3

I have defined a Controller in CakePHP 1.3 legacy application running on IIS server windows server 2012, How do I access a view via its controller such that the URL route conforms to application/controller/view.

```
<?php
class NamesController extends AppController {
    var $helpers = array ('Html','Form');
    var $name = 'Names';


}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can define a function to access the view within the controller class, e.g.

```
function view() {
        //code for the function 
    }
```

complete code with function defined

```
<?php
class NamesController extends AppController {
    var $helpers = array ('Html','Form');
    var $name = 'Names';

    function view() {
        //code for the function 
    }
}
?>
```

route will now be able to accessed and view request is possible via the route URL [application/controller/view](https://#)
Ensure that associated view is created in the views folder.
URL Rewrite on IIS must be installed, and web.config setup with proper rewrite rules.